Livewire3: Opening modal component from a different component
I've tried following a number of guides and videos. What I'm trying to do is open a modal from my listing view, the modal is a livewire component.
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Customer;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Customer;

class CreateCustomerModal extends Component
{
    public $nit;
    public $razon_social;
    public $phone_number;
    public $address;
    public $isOpen = false;

    protected $rules = [
        'nit' => 'required|unique:customers,nit',
        'razon_social' => 'required|min:3',
        'phone_number' => 'required|min:7',
        'address' => 'required|min:5',
    ];

    protected $listeners = ['openModal' => 'openModal'];

    public function openModal($data): void
    {
        $this->isOpen = true;
    }

    public function closeModal(): void
    {
        $this->isOpen = false;
    }

    public function save(): void
    {
        $this->validate();

        Customer::create([
            'nit' => $this->nit,
            'razon_social' => $this->razon_social,
            'phone_number' => $this->phone_number,
            'address' => $this->address,
        ]);

        $this->closeModal();
    }

    public function render(): View|Application|Factory|\Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application
    {
        return view('livewire.customer.create-customer-modal');
    }
}

my create-customer-modal.blode.php file looks like this:
<div
    x-data="{ open: @entangle('isOpen') }"
    x-on:open-modal.window="open = true; $wire.openModal()"
    x-show="open"
    x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-200"
    x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0"
    x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100"
    x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-200"
    x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
    x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0"
    class="fixed inset-0 z-50 overflow-y-auto"
    aria-labelledby="modal-title" role="dialog" aria-modal="true"
>
    <div class="flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">
        <div class="fixed inset-0 transition-opacity" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-500 opacity-75"></div>
        </div>
        <span class="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen" aria-hidden="true">&#8203;</span>
        <div class="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full">
            <form wire:submit.prevent="save">
                <div class="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
                    <h3 class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">Create New Customer</h3>
                    <div class="mt-2">
                        <input type="text" wire:model="nit" class="border border-gray-300 rounded p-2 w-full" placeholder="NIT">
                        @error('nit') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="mt-2">
                        <input type="text" wire:model="razon_social" class="border border-gray-300 rounded p-2 w-full" placeholder="Razon Social">
                        @error('razon_social') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="mt-2">
                        <input type="text" wire:model="phone_number" class="border border-gray-300 rounded p-2 w-full" placeholder="Phone Number">
                        @error('phone_number') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="mt-2">
                        <input type="text" wire:model="address" class="border border-gray-300 rounded p-2 w-full" placeholder="Address">
                        @error('address') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:px-6 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse">
                    <button type="submit" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="mt-3 w-full inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-gray-300 shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-white text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 sm:mt-0 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm" @click="open = false">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

My button code in another blade view triggered by a controller is:
<button
                class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded"
                wire:click="$dispatch('open-modal')">
                Create New Customer
            </button>

I've tried using @click, modifying my controller to use On annotation and many other options. Nothing really seems to work.
If I put a button within my modal blade view like
<button @click="isOpen = true" wire:click="openModal" class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded">
                Create Customer
            </button>

seems to work. But I need to be able to open the modal from other components. I've been reading up on old questions and all I can find for like 5 hrs now. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. If someone could guide me towards the right path I would appreciate it.
Thank you!

Basic question: are the modal and the other view containing the button present at the same time in the browser page?

it seems that my html isnt been added when i try to include it, do you know why this might be?

I ask again: are the components all included on the same page? For example one includes the other or both are included by a parent

@livewire('customer.create-customer-modal')
@livewire('customer.edit-customer-modal')
im using this but i dont see the html in the page, not sure why its not being added. it should be added

Let's try this: edit the question and insert all the relevant code, we need at least the view part and the class of the component that includes create-customer-modal. Take inspiration from How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example to understand how to proceed

Ensure Event Emission:
<button
    class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded"
    wire:click="$dispatch('open-modal')"
    x-on:click="console.log('Event emitted')">
    Create New Customer
</button>

Check Event Listener:
public function openModal($data): void
{
    $this->isOpen = true;
    logger('Modal opened'); // Add this line
}

Alpine.js Integration:
<script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>

Blade View:
<div
    x-data="{ open: @entangle('isOpen') }"
    x-on:open-modal.window="open = true; console.log('Modal event received'); $wire.openModal()"
    x-show="open"
    x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-200"
    x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0"
    x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100"
    x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-200"
    x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
    x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0"
    class="fixed inset-0 z-50 overflow-y-auto"
    aria-labelledby="modal-title" role="dialog" aria-modal="true"
>
    <!-- Modal content -->
</div>

